# Get all realm Objects in Android

Tags: android, realm

Is there a way to get all existing Objects in Realm.

There are around 1000 Objects(Tables), each Object has 10000+ items.
For every 1 hour some items get's expired.

```
// Class[] clazzez = realm.getSchema();

Class[] clazzez = new Class[] { // How to get all classes dynamically?
    Demo.class, AnotherDemo.class, SomeOtherDemo.class
};


// To delete expired items
for(Class clazz: clazzez) {
    realm.where(clazz)
            .greaterThan("maxAge", new Date().getTime())
            .findAll()
            .deleteAllFromRealm();
}
```

It's very difficult to keep track of all classes. How to get all classes dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `realmConfiguration.getRealmObjectClasses();` (0.88.0+).

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()...build();
// ...
Set<Class<? extends RealmModel>> schemaClasses = realmConfiguration.getRealmObjectClasses(); // <---

// To delete expired items
for(Class clazz: schemaClasses) {
    realm.where(clazz)
            .greaterThan("maxAge", new Date().getTime()) // <-- assumes existence of "maxAge" field
            .findAll()
            .deleteAllFromRealm();
}
```